# How to make jQuery functions sequential

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadStuff(someURL, someID);
  showStuff('foo');
});
```

showStuff() relies on content generated by loadStuff() but it seems as if showStuff() is jumping the gun before said content is available.  How can I force them to run sequentially?

Update: Yes, there are ajax calls in loadStuff but unfortunately they're jsonp so can't be called synchronously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rewrite it as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadStuff(someURL, someID, function() { showStuff('foo'); });
});
```

where the third parameter of loadStuff is the callback to call after the content is loaded

Answer (score 6):

The elegant way is using [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), in particular [Deferred.pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/). See the question [Understanding jQuery Deferred.pipe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921283/understanding-jquery-deferred-pipe) for an example.

Comment: Yeah, thats definitely a nice way of doing this. http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/ explains this nicely. The only catch being you need to use Jquery 1.5 or above

Comment: Warning: As of jQuery 1.8, the [deferred.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) method (...) replacing the now-deprecated deferred.pipe() method

Answer (score 0):

call showStuff in the success callback of ajax call that loadStuff makes.

See also
[How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-req)

Answer (score 0):

They *do* run sequentially, but stuff inside `loadStuff` may not be (especially if `loadStuff` is performing *asynchronous HTTP requests*). It's the code *inside* `loadStuff` that's not running sequentially.

Usually I'd just say "we need *way* more code context to answer this question", but there's enough to say this:

Either use a synchronous HTTP request, or move the call to `showStuff` into the on-success callback for your asynchronous one, so that it only fires when the request has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

Pass `showStuff` as a delegate to a callback to be invoked upon a successful response from your AJAX call within `loadStuff()`.

Example:

```
function loadStuff() {

      $.ajax({
      url: "Stuff/GetStuff",
      success: function(){
        showStuff();
      }
    });

}
```

Or, the less elegant way, just check to see if data is loaded every so often, until it is:

```
var timerId = setInterval(showStuff, 50);

function showStuff() {
  if (stuffIsLoadded) {
    // do show stuff stuffs.
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
}
```