# Passing data between deferred functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using some deferred functions with the .done so, I'm having something like that:

```
askTime(number).done(formatTime).done(function(html){
   times += html;
});
```

But although `formatTime` returns `data`, the `html` var has the data returned by `askTime`.

I don't know where if the problem. `formatTime` receives a data variable which is returned by `askTime` but if I put:

```
askTime(number).done(formatTime(data)).done(function(html)
```

It says that `data` isn't defined.

Comment: Try askTime(number).done(function(data) {formatTime(data);}).done(function(html)

Comment: Inconsistency in Q, But although formatTime returns data & formatTime receives a data variable. Code for askTIme, formatTime will help.

Comment: @hungryMind both functions works since both were part of the same function I splitted to be able to use them elsewhere.

Comment: @hungryMind also, your first try (although) seemed logicall to me, didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To chain deferred methods, you need to invoke `.pipe()`.

Have a look: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/

Comment: I'm having a look but unable to understand correctly. Examples given are a bit hard or unclear (for me at least)

Comment: @AntonioLaguna Just try ".pipe()" instead of the first ".done()" in your code.

Comment: I picked up the final code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921283/understanding-jquery-deferred-pipe and works and seems to understandable to me but this is not exactly what comes in the docs. Could you give me more light please?

Comment: Thanks again @jAndy you seem to be a master of the deferred!