# jquery deferred passing down the chain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code.

```
function doReq() {
    return $.get('http://localhost:5000/fun/test.php').done(
        function(data) {
            var x = data + "uui";

    }).done(
        function(data) {
            alert(x);
        }
    );
}

doReq();
```

x is undefined, because it is out of scope.

Is there a way to pass additional variables, apart from just data down the pipeline?

Comment: Just as you're alluding in your question, take a look at the deferred() object from jquery:  http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357188/passing-data-between-deferred-functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the same deferred object, as you have no control over the arguments passed to `resolveWith()` in this case.  However, the callbacks will run in the order defined, so you could define `var x` at the top of the function, and it would be accessible in both callbacks' scope (and those functions will manipulate the variable sequentially).

Otherwise, you would need a second deferred, and you could resolve it with whatever arguments you want.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain, so I can improve this answer?