# jquery ajax and pipe

Tags: jquery, pipe

I have the following code:

```
(saveData())
.pipe(function(data){return sendhandovermail($('#editperson_id').val());})
.pipe(function(data){setHistory(_eciId,'4','12',true);})
.pipe(function(data){window.location.href = 'input.cfm?m=4&id=45';})
.fail(function(data){$('##msgDialogDetail').html("Error while saving. Please contact bla@blup.com");});
```

The code works (no errors) but... I was told .pipe() method will do all ajax calls one after the other. IF A returns, B will start. Though when I run it, it's not the case.
Am I understanding it wrong, or how should I write this chain to have it execute one after the other?

Comment: yes. First argument is `doneFilter` that will be executed once the first ajax request is completed and i think all will be executed in parallel.

Comment: can you elaborate? the first argument of what / where?

Comment: I assume saveData makes an ajax request and returns a deferred object. All pipes are applied on that deferred object unless every function is not returning a deferred object and thats why all functions within pipe will be executed in parallel.

Comment: every function is returning a deferred object

Comment: then all functions will be executed synchronously one after the other

Comment: okay sorry, only the last .pipe is NOT a deff. object

Comment: but that's my problem, they're not executing one after the other. The refresh happens before the setHIstory()

Comment: @PoeHaH, you're ignoring the value returned by `setHistory()`, not returning it.

Comment: may be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921283/understanding-jquery-deferred-pipe

Answer (score 0):

how should I write this chain to have it execute one after the other?

you should return a promise in pre pipe and the later will run according the promise that pre pipe returned.

like this:

```js
var posting = $.post('/step1', data1)
            .pipe(function () {
                return $.post('/step2', data2);
            })
            .pipe(function () {
                return $.post('/step3', data3);
            });
```

we should use `then` function instead of `pipe` in 1.8+ jQuery.