# jQuery animation queue for many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've got a lot of elements that are different somehow `(b,c,d,e,f classes)`, but each of them has something the same - `'a class'`. How to make some animation `quene` that will make them animate one after another in `FIFO` order (first in, first out)?

Callback's are going crazy with it as there are many elements and I cant estamine what div will be called when.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/AZtNu/1/

Comment: Please don't post questions which contain nothing useful except a JSFiddle. Not how Stack Overflow works. Your question needs to be self contained and answerable without opening *any* external links. You can then supplement it with a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your animations are all the same kind(animating left to 50) but done on multiple elements, you can do it this way:

```
nextAnim( $('.a') );

function nextAnim(elems) {
    elems.eq(0).animate({'left':50}, function() {
             nextAnim( elems.slice(1) );  // slice off the first element
    });
}
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/E5RXK/)

Answer (score 0):

[Understanding jQuery Deferred.pipe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921283/understanding-jquery-deferred-pipe)

You can try to use deferred object if you're feeling like learning something new and doing things in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I've used

```
$('.a').filter(function(){ return $(this).is(':animated')}).length
```

to know if any of items is alredy animated, and I'm firing animations only when no of them is animating